# Git workflow multiple repositories and rebasing(?)

Tags: git, version-control, repository, workflow, project

Hey guys I've been wondering if this could be feasible? I've been pondering over it for hours and I can't get my head wrapped around it!

Say I have X clients interested in a e-commerce/cms system ( basically whatever ), in my perfect world I would like to have this situation ( If you think I'm crazy convince me otherwise please! I'm open for different suggestions ):

**Software Repository ( A )** *being the e-commerce system or cms*, at it's latest version. Which would be periodically updated depending on vendor release cyclces. ( Yes I'm aware it might not be the best idea to version the software dependency in here, but I'm interested if this 3 layer "cake" is actually do-able ).

**Design Repository ( B )**, multiple of these containing a certain base style to start off from. Tied to the software vendor's approach.

**Client Repository ( C )**, this would be an initial checkout of the master of A, containing a certain style of design, say B-2. And would be updated with specific client features, styles etc.

Now let's say we've made a client happy with our project and I would like to make them even happier keeping their CMS / e-commerce solution safe by providing regular updates, is there any (easy) way to do this sort of fashion of work:

1. Update the software repository with a new version of the e-commerce / cms software
2. Commit these changes
3. Pull these changes into the corresponding design ( and of course spawning multiple, if necessary ). And provide an update of new features in a design or what-so-ever.
4. Commit these changes into the specific design repository.
5. Now we start pulling our client repositories and update these with the previous changes, where-after we are able to deploy.

The only way I've seemed to figure this out is based on git-rebasing within a single repository, between several branches, however this doesn't seem like the ideal solution to me.

**Am I a lunatic? Or do I need a smack with trout and get an easy solution?**

Thanks for taking the time to read / respond!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it would be better to 1) enable different configurations of the software and if that fails 2) use Git branches.

I think it would be easier to maintain a single code base. Try to enable most of the differences as configurations based on configuration files or something similar.

If you really need large and permanent differences in different versions of the code, use permanent Git branches, so that you can at least easily `merge` or `cherry-pick` features and patches between the branches.

Comment: I've slightly adjusted my question in between, I woulden't like ending up with over a 100 of clients in one single repository, what would you recommend?

Comment: @wtfzdotnet but surely those 100 clients would not all have wildly different needs? Can you parametrize the differences?

Comment: Say specific (bought) plugins on a client basis, where these packages between clients would differ, but the initial base for the layout being the same. E.g. client A does not get a refund-plugin because they didn't opt for it, but client B wanted it and got it ( providing this might even be maintained in a 4th repository )?

Comment: @wtfzdotnet if the plugins are stand-alone products, then sure, you could have a repository for each of those.

Comment: Keeping it in simple terms, how would you go about this whole tree ( if possible ) with different repositories where client A has an red website and client B has an blue one? For some reason I just don't feel comfortable with having a ton of branches for each client or specific design style?

Comment: @wtfzdotnet I would have a config file with a color setting. When you deploy the site you apply a transformation of the config file that sets the color to red when deploying to A and blue when deploying to B.